# Can an empty for-loop be "correct"?

Tags: c, for-loop

I have a doubt about the for loop of the following code in C:

```
main()
{
    int i=1;
    for(;;)
    {
        printf("%d",i++);
        if(i>10)
        break;
    }
}
```

I saw this code in a question paper. I thought that the for loop won't work because it has no condition in it. But the answer says that the code has no error. Is it true ? If true, how ?

Comment: Did you *try* it? What were your results?

Comment: @meagar I have no C in my system. Thats why I asked you people.

Comment: @Tom You cannot learn C without programming, for the same reason as you can't learn swimming without water.

Comment: @Lundin Yeah, I know. I have learned C for some time earlier. Now I don't have C in my system. Thats why I had to ask my doubt here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regular for loop has three parts:

- Initialization
- Condition
- Increment

Usually they are written like this:

```
for (initialization; condition; increment) { statements }
```

But all three parts are optional. In your case, all parts are indeed missing from the for loop, *but are present elsewhere*:

- The initialization is `int i=1`
- The condition is `if (i>10) break`
- The increment is `i++`

The above code can be equivalently written as:

```
for (int i=1; i <= 10; i++) {
  printf("%d", i);
}
```

So all the parts necessary for a for loop are present, except they are not inside the actual `for` construct. The loop would work, it's just not a very readable way to write it.

Answer (score 3):

The `for (;;)` loop is an infinite loop, though in this case the body of the loop takes actions that ensure that it does not run forever.  Each component of the control is optional.  A missing condition is equivalent to `1` or `true`.

The loop would be more clearly written as:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
    printf("%d", i);
```

---

We can still debate whether the output is sensible:

```
12345678910
```

could be produced more easily with:

```
puts("12345678910");
```

and you get a newline at the end.  But these are meta-issues.  As written, the loop 'works'.  It is syntactically correct.  It also terminates.

Answer (score 2):

It's an infinite loop. When there is not a condition in `for` and we use `;;` the statements in the body of `for` will be executed infinitely. However because there is a `break` statement inside it's body, if the variable i will be greater than 10, the execution will be stopped.

As it is stated in MSDN:

> The statement `for(;;)` is the customary way to produce an infinite loop which can only be exited with a break, goto, or return statement.

For further documentation, please look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3e6x17s.aspx).

Comment: This is most certainly not an infinite loop since it has an embedded exit condition

Comment: @Avish: the loop control is an infinite loop; the loop body ensures that it does not run for ever.

Comment: The downvote was mine, because your answer incorrectly said that this is an infinite loop which was wrong and misleading in the context of the question ("is this code correct?"). Now that you edited it it's more correct, and I will remove the downvote.

Comment: @Avish thank you for your explanation ! Just i was wondering what was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You are not specifying any parameters or conditions in your for loop, therefore, it would be an endless loop.  Since there is a break condition based on another external variable, it would not be infinite.

This should be re-written as:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    printf("%d",i++);
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if a for loop is not having any condition in it, the needed conditions are specified inside the for loop.

The printf statement has `i++` which keeps on increasing the value of `i` and next we have if statement which will check if value of i is less than 10. Once i is greater than 10 it will break the loop.

Comment: "...for loop is not having any condition..." /-- "...the needed conditions are inside the for loop". Huh?

Comment: isn't it clear? The usual conditions are not mentioned in for statement but we have similar conditions inside for loop.